# Is there any diff between call .mutable_mynestedmsg() and .mynestedmsg()?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, mutable

I'm new to the google protobuf and what to know is there any different between following methods:

```
1) 
foo.mutable_bar()->set_somefield(...)
```

and

```
2)
nestedmsg = foo.bar(); 
nestedmsg.set_somefield() (where bar is message)
```

?

As I found foo.bar() is not working for me. The different in the docs is that mutable call returns pointer instead default_instance. But why the second way is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second version shouldn't even compile:  `bar()` returns a const reference, but `set_somefield()` is not a const method.  Do not use `const_cast` to get around this!

The difference between the methods is that `mutable_bar()` actually initializes the `bar` field with a new sub-message if it is not already present.  That is, if `has_bar()` will always return `true` after `mutable_bar()` even if it was `false` before hand.  `bar()`, on the other hand, never modifies the message, so does not affect `has_bar()`.  If the `bar` field isn't set, then `bar()` returns a reference to the type's default instance, which you should *never* modify -- that's why it's const.

If you need to modify the sub-message, you must always use the `mutable_` variant.  Don't worry, it never returns a null pointer.